# Remove character based on condition and position in string - R

Tags: r, string, substring, character, data-cleaning

I am cleaning up a dataset with a character variable like this:

```
df <- c("2015  000808", "2013  000041", "2015  000005", "2015  301585", "2015  311585", "2014  380096", "2013  100041")
```

So I can achieve this result, where the 000s in front of the second number are removed and each number is pasted together:

```
"2015808"
"201341"
"20155"
"2015301585"
"2015311585"
"2014380096"
"2013100041"
```

I am stuck trying to find the best way to remove the 0s that occur before the number in the second part of the string. I have looked at `gsub` and `substring` but I am bit confused how to remove a pattern of zeros based on their position as well as on conditions? Something along the lines of "remove one or more zeros only if they precede number 1-9 and are in position 7-11".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While akrun's approach is the one that should be used. Here is `stringr` composition:

1. with `word(df, 1)` we take the left part of the string
2. with `word(df, -1)` we take the right part (here we use
   2a. `str_remove_all` with regex `^0+` to remove leading zeros.
3. Finally we use `str_c` to combine both parts:

```
library(stringr)
str_c(word(df,1), str_remove_all(word(df, -1), '^0+'))
```

```
[1] "2015808"    "201341"     "20155"      "2015301585" "2015311585" "2014380096" "2013100041"
```

Answer (score 3):

We may use `read.table` to read as two columns (which automatically reads as `numeric` columns by using the default space separator and numeric class won't allow 0 prefix, thus strips off the 0s) and then `paste` the data.frame columns by row by using `do.call`

```
do.call(paste0, read.table(text = df, header = FALSE))
[1] "2015808"    "201341"     "20155"      "2015301585" "2015311585" "2014380096" "2013100041"
```

---

Or with `sub` - match one or more spaces (`\\s+`) followed by zero or more (`*`) 0, and replace with blank (`""`)

```
sub("\\s+0*", "", df)
[1] "2015808"    "201341"     "20155"      "2015301585" "2015311585" "2014380096" "2013100041"
```